# memory leak in appdelegate in swift language

Tags: swift3, appdelegate

please can fix my problem about memory leak i have got the leak in app delegate and i don't know when and how can i fix it  ?
the following part of my code which  is have leak from instrument which is must i release it from app delegate ?

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
   var window: UIWindow?
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
        UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white

        return true
    }

}
```

thanks a lot

Comment: This is the beginning of the app cycle. It has no leaks, in instruments you need to dig deeper after this method to get the exact line where the leak occurs.

Comment: i have this code only and with keep all method which is did enter background and so on and also i get the memory leak, is anything here must i release it?

Comment: Don't you have any ViewControllers?

Comment: i have an project on tab bar controller have 3 view controller  with each view controller  navigation controller

Comment: And your controllers don't have any code or custom controls?

Comment: i have no only each view controller have views like web view and buttons and another have table view

Comment: If I didn't have any code and used only built-in controls I would ignore the issue, or report it to apple. Have a nice day!